Cyrillic characters in the names of classes
Is it somehow possible to use Cyrillic characters in the names of classes and their instances?
When using Cyrillic characters in class names, an error occurs "Name is not a valid identifier". Is it possible to somehow use Cyrillic characters in the names of classes and their instances? For example, using some kind of add-ons to the program or using annotations?

You can but you need to single quote them: model 'фотф' should work.

No, it's not possible.
The Modelica Specification defines how identifiers are constructed in Section 2.3.1 Identifiers.
You can choose between two forms, the "normal" identifier (IDENT) and quoted identifier (Q-IDENT).
Quoting from the specification:

The first form always starts with a letter or underscore (‘_’), followed by any number of letters, digits, or underscores.
[...]
The second form (Q-IDENT) starts with a single quote, followed by a sequence of any printable ASCII character, where single-quote must be preceded by backslash, and terminated by a single quote [...].

Since OpenModelica tries to be standard compliant this won't change.
